# Change search criteria when HeaderFilter results is zero

Tags: tabulator

### I'd like the search criteria to adapt when a user searches using the headerFilter search box, swapping between "equal" / "like" search rules depending on number of results

**example > values are ["a", "b", "ac", "ab"] for column**

If `"a"` is searched, only show results where `value_search === row_value`.
If the previous criteria returns 0 rows, change search criteria to `row_value.includes(value_search)`

Thus searching the above example values should result in the following

`Search : "a"` should be `Results : "a"` only

`Search : "b"` should be `Results : "b"` only

`Search : "ac"` should be `Results : "ac"` only

`Search : "c"` should be `Results : "ac"` (this is thus a "like" search as its not an exact match to any values)

`Search : "ab"` should be `Results : "ab"` only - (not `"a"` nor `"b"` as an "equal" search has returned results)

Im not sure if this is possible but would be great if it is. I have sofar not been able to get this working.

---

It would also be great if the dropdown values (when used with `headerFilterParams: {values: true}`) also filtered with the users' input.  For example the suggestions should react with `"a", "ac", "ab"` if `"a"` was entered into the header filter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a custom header filter function to use any rule you like for filtering, the ***headerFilterFunc*** column definition property can be used for this:

```
function customHeaderFilter(headerValue, rowValue, rowData, filterParams){
    //headerValue - the value of the header filter element
    //rowValue - the value of the column in this row
    //rowData - the data for the row being filtered
    //filterParams - params object passed to the headerFilterFuncParams property

    return rowData.name == filterParams.name && rowValue < headerValue; //must return a boolean, true if it passes the filter.
}

//column definition object in table constructor
{title:"Age", field:"age", headerFilter:"input", headerFilterPlaceholder:"Max Age", headerFilterFunc:customHeaderFilter, headerFilterFuncParams:{name:"bob"}}
```

Checkout the [Filter Documentation](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.5/filter) for full details

The filter function itself is doing the filtering so is unaware of the number of rows that make it through. but you could use the ***dataFiltered*** callback to check the number of rows that made it through the filter, as it is passed in a row array.

```
dataFiltered:function(filters, rows){
    //filters - array of filters currently applied
    //rows - array of row components that pass the filters
}
```

You could then change the table filter if the row array length is 0

Comment: This is great, however the filter will return "like" results **and** "equal" result in your first code snippet, which will pollute the results. You second snippet addresses this but I'm not aware of any filter triggers that can be used to trigger the headerFilter search, nor on-the-fly headerFilterFunc change method

Comment: Maybe adding `table.setFilter("age", ">", 10);` after the `dataFiltered` func could work..

Comment: the filter was more of an example of a custom filter, you can use any logic you like in there, it is up to you to define it., you can use the column.setHeaderFilterValue("steve"); function on a column component to set the header filter for a specific column

Comment: P.S. Im the chap that wrote Tabulator

Comment: Is it possible to rather filter the results in the dropdown as you type? This would be ideal